# How to move css elements by their common html class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Bit of a noob here! I'm working in pure javascript with the assistance of HTML and CSS, no engine. I'm trying to move a displayed tank sprite composed of 3 parts: tracks, chassis and a turret.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='.css'>
        <div class='tank' id='tracks'></div>
        <div class='tank' id='chasis'></div>
        <div class='tank' id='turret'></div>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src='.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here I created the three div elements with their unique id for the tracks, chassis and turret. They all share the common class tank.

```
.tank {
    height: 31px;
    width: 31px;
    position: absolute;
}

#tracks {
    background: url("tracks.png");
}

#chasis {
    background: url("chasis.png");
}

#turret {
    background: url("turret.png");
}
```

In my CSS code, I attributed all the properties that the 3 components share to their class, so they share the same size and position. Since each of the three elements has a unique image that cannot be shared, I attributed it to each element by id.

```
var tracks = document.getElementById('tracks');
var chasis = document.getElementById('chasis');
var turret = document.getElementById('turret');

tracks.style.top = '167px';
chasis.style.top = '167px';
turret.style.top = '167px';
```

This code has done the trick in the sense that it has successfully moved each component down by 167px but I want to avoid rewriting all that every time I want to move the tank by its components.

```
var tank = document.getElementsByClassName('tank');

tank.style.top = '167px';
```

So instead, I tried to move the entire tank by class but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try putting the divs in the body section and your js in the head section.

also add a [0] to the class as follows,

```
var tank = document.getElementsByClassName('tank')[0];
```

edited cause i realised they were not in a div with tank class as suggested by Nex

Comment: Didn't work, it just displayed the tank as it was. Though when I left the divs and js code as it was in the html and added on the [0] to the js, the tracks moved down but the rest stayed at the top. That's because, the tracks are the zeroth element of the class tank.

Comment: yeah if they were all in a div like Nex suggests then it should work with [0] added to the JS

Comment: Nope, tried it just now. I did the divs like @Nex suggested and put them in the body whilst the js in the head and added a [0], still didn't work, the tank didn't even display let alone move.

Comment: The console says: TypeError: tank is undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="tank">
        <div id='tracks'></div>
        <div id='chasis'></div>
        <div id='turret'></div>
</div>
```

Can you just try this? So you have TANK which has all the parts inside now.

Comment: .style can not be applied on nodelist get by getElementsByClassName function.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName`, it returns Node list in Object format. So you can not directly apply style on it. You need to traverse the list using array functions. To get array list you can use querySelectorAll.

```js
const tanks = document.querySelectorAll('.tank');
tanks.forEach(function(tank, index){
  tank.style.marginTop = '167px';
});
```

```html
<div class="tank">1</div>
<div class="tank">2</div>
```

Comment: Only the tracks moved, the chassis and turret stayed as they were.

Comment: @krecik2000, Edited my answer. querySelector only returns 1st element. So need to use querySelectorAll.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found an alternate way to achieve this:

Leave the html and css as they were.

```
var tracks = document.getElementById('tracks');
var chasis = document.getElementById('chasis');
var turret = document.getElementById('turret');

var tank = [tracks, chasis, turret];

for (var i = 0; i < tank.length; i++) {
   tank[i].style.top = '167px';
}
```

Scrap the js and throw in the above.

Call the elements by their ids and create an array tank to contain them. Then loop through the array while the tank.length (which is 3) is greater than i, move the tank elements by 167px. Since i can only be 0, 1 and 2, the 3 elements (labelled 0, 1 and 2) are moved.

Later if you need to access the singular elements you can call them by their ids or find them in the tank array like so: tank[0], tank[1] or tank[2].